Microsoft Authentication "login.microsoftonline.com/kmsi" request is responding with 400 : BAD REQUEST in JMeter
after saving the needed requests for bypassing the Microsoft authentication by saving the requests as .har from Firefox then worked on the dynamic values in JMeter all the below requests get passed successfully returning the needed values

https://login.microsoftonline.com/68283f3b-8487-4c86-adb3-a5228f18b893/saml2
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType?mkt=en-GB
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/instrumentation/dssostatus
https://login.microsoftonline.com/68283f3b-8487-4c86-adb3-a5228f18b893/login

I've tried to pass the final retrieved dynamic values from the login request by extracting them as in the following screenshot
image demonstrating that the values extracted from the login request get passed to the kmsi request
on the other hand after executing the script the kmsi request return the response 400 : bad request while there is no difference in the request form sent compared to the one loaded on firefox network panel from my perspective, please check the following image
Image demonstrating request body of the kmsi api that return 400 : bad request
expected result is that the kmsi request should return the value for both "SAMLResponse" , "RelayState" to be passed to the /samlauthn/ api
kmsi api request headers
please help what could be the reason for having this bad request from the /kmsi request


Well, first of all I can see that recorded request goes to https://login.microsoftonline.com/68283f3b-8487-4c86-adb3-a5228f18b893/login and your request is targeting https://login.microsoftonline.com/login. You might want to take a look at this difference first.
I'm not sure whether this 68283f3b-8487-4c86-adb3-a5228f18b893 guy is static or dynamic, in the latter case you need to correlate it as well and ensure that the recorded value is replaced in the Referer header
You didn't bother to provide either information from the Network tab of your browser developer tools or comparison of requests sent by browser and by JMeter from a sniffer tool so we cannot provide comprehensive help, but one thing is obvious: HTTP status 400 means "Bad Request" and the request is "bad" due to missing or improperly implemented correlation. It might be the case that correlated values need to be URL-encoded or decoded somehow or you've extracted them not completely or something like this.

